# Teen to ya book about a vacation home and a girl and grandparents

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a YA novel about a teenage girl who ends the summer with her grandparents in a rental house. Every time they open up the front door they're transported to a new location.

On one occasion they go to New York and they pick up her male cousin. At some point in time they're transported to Russia where a man is injured and they bring him in the house the back door that leads to a giant forest with these giant tunnels that have been dug by giant worms.

Somewhere in the upstairs there's a tunnel that you can crawl through that leads to like a mirror-image of the house

Comment: Do you know approximately it was published? Anything about the cover? Any other details would be helpful.